# How to override the styles in materialui-daterange-picker?

Tags: material-ui

I am using https://github.com/jungsoft/materialui-daterange-picker which uses Material UI. It uses makeStyles to override the styles. I am trying to apply my own styles to things like button disabled, filled, outline, etc. How do you override a makeStyles override?

I tried directly overriding classes like this, but no success.

```
export const useDateRangePickerStyles = makeStyles({    
   '& button:disabled .materialui-daterange-picker-MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary': {
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)'
    },
    '& .materialui-daterange-picker-makeStyles-filled': {
      backgroundColor: '#03DAC5'
    },
    '& .materialui-daterange-picker-makeStyles-highlighted': {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(3, 218, 197, 0.08)'
    },
    '& .materialui-daterange-picker-makeStyles-outlined': {
      borderColor: '#03DAC5'
    },
    '& .MuiPaper-elevation': {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      transition: 'none'
    }
})
```

I even tried creating a new makeStyles with a hierarchy of MaterialUI class overrides. No success.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue came up multiple times with the plugin and the "Issues" section of the github package contains some css hacks that helped.